# Admin or control panel

Tags: javascript, html, cpanel

I can do fine apps or websites, but there is a little use of them without control system.

How can I make an admin panel or how it's called. So that the user can add required components without coding. Just with some buttons and text areas, like in Wordpress.

I don't know how or what should I search on the Internet on this topic.

I know HTML/ JS / VUE basics / SASS. How can I use this knowledge to make a control system of my websites or apps. Or probably I should learn something new?

Please, advise how to reach my goal.

Comment: Hey Ren, welcome to SO. this is not the site to ask for recommendations for what software or libraries to use. it's to help a specific problem in code. you could try: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is something like a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system).
A **content manager system** allow the user to drag and drop elements on the page. Basically, it's making a website with blocks.

Hope this helps.